# How to get HTML-formatted detailed info about an item from an unformatted ListView?

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm getting JSON data from an API that I have to show on the main page as a ListView. Each of the displayed items is also HTML-formatted, but:
1) There should be no formatting whatsoever on the main page
2) An item should be displayed on a separate page WITH the HTML-formatting when clicking on it.

How can I get to first display all the items unformatted, but then move to the detailed page and see the selected item as it really is?

Comment: You need to use an HTML parser library that gets the plain text out off the HTML, but view it (without parsing) in a web view when moving to the detail page.

Comment: @mshwf How do I get to display other elements on the page with WebView? Right now they're taking up space and the whole page is unscrollable. Instead, the WebView gets narrower (but is scrollable within itself) the more other elements there are. Is there a way to make WebView show the same info, but act just like other elements?

Comment: Update your question with you've tried, with code, and the problem with it, and I'll try to help